# Convert json object to formData (HTML5 Object)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, form-data

I have seen many posts about converting formData to JSON object, however, I have the exact opposite use case. I have a JSON object which I would like to convert to a formData object as this is required by my endpoint API.

My code right now:

```
formdata = new FormData();
var uploadJson = {
  "default_lang": "en",
  "words": [
    {
      "desc": $scope.selectedWord,
      "enabled": true,
      "examples": $scope.examples
    }
  ]
};

formdata.append('file', uploadJson);
```

However, formdata is always empty even after appending uploadJson.

Does anyone know how to fix/do that?

Comment: FormData always runs `.toString()` on appended fields, so it runs: uploadJson.toString() which results in [object Object] (at least in my case). Can you post how you check if formdata is empty? Also ajax code maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try stringifying the ***javascript object*** to json.

```
formdata.append('file', JSON.stringify(uploadJson));
```

Note that JSON is a string data format and there is [no such thing as a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)